# Setting a specific ID for priviledges in Nexus API

Tags: curl, nexus

I'm working on automatically creating private repositories in Nexus OSS.
For now, I'm thinking about using `curl` to do so.
Here, I want to create

1. 2 private repositories(snapshot,release)
2. Priviledges for each repository(create,read,update,delete)
3. Roles to add the priviledges
4. Users with roles set

I currently have trouble with adding priviledges to roles, because the IDs of generated priviledges look like some random IDs.

```
curl -s --user <user>:<password> -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'\
-d '{"data":{"name":"<repo-name>-release","description":"<repo-name>-release","type":"target","repositoryTargetId":"any","repositoryId":"<repo-name>-release","repositoryGroupId":"","method":["create","read","update","delete"]}}'\
https://<my-nexus-server>/nexus/service/local/privileges_target
```

It returns

```
{"data":[{"id":"19de4d5c87506","resourceURI":"https://<my-nexus-server>/nexus/service/local/privileges_target/19de4d5c87506","name":"<repo-name>-release - (create)","description":"<repo-name>-release","type":"target","userManaged":true,"properties":[{"key":"repositoryTargetId","value":"any"},{"key":"method","value":"create,read"},{"key":"repositoryId","value":"<repo-name>-release"},{"key":"repositoryGroupId","value":""}]},{"id":"19de4d638eafd","resourceURI":"https://<my-nexus-server>/nexus/service/local/privileges_target/19de4d638eafd","name":"123-release - (read)","description":"<repo-name>-release","type":"target","userManaged":true,"properties":[{"key":"repositoryTargetId","value":"any"},{"key":"method","value":"read"},{"key":"repositoryId","value":"<repo-name>-release"},{"key":"repositoryGroupId","value":""}]},{"id":"19de4d6c197e0","resourceURI":"https://<my-nexus-server>/nexus/service/local/privileges_target/19de4d6c197e0","name":"<repo-name>-release - (update)","description":"<repo-name>-release","type":"target","userManaged":true,"properties":[{"key":"repositoryTargetId","value":"any"},{"key":"method","value":"update,read"},{"key":"repositoryId","value":"<repo-name>-release"},{"key":"repositoryGroupId","value":""}]},{"id":"19de4d756fde5","resourceURI":"https://<my-nexus-server>/nexus/service/local/privileges_target/19de4d756fde5","name":"<repo-name>-release - (delete)","description":"<repo-name>-release","type":"target","userManaged":true,"properties":[{"key":"repositoryTargetId","value":"any"},{"key":"method","value":"delete,read"},{"key":"repositoryId","value":"<repo-name>-release"},{"key":"repositoryGroupId","value":""}]}]}
```

I want to add these generated priviledges to a role.

Is there a way to

1. Set the ID when generating priviledges via REST API?

or

2. Add these generated priviledges (with random IDs) to a role?

Comment: There is no way to set these ID's, you need to parse the result back after you've created the privileges and use the generated ID's in the next call.

Comment: @rseddon thanks for the reply. I think I'll stop being lazy and write a little script to parse them.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I decided to write a script in python.
I'm a noob in python, so I appreciate any comments.

```
import requests
import json

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# Server Settings
baseurl=<my nexus>
auth=HTTPBasicAuth(<user>,<password>)

# need a dictionary for name to id coordination
dict = {}
url = "/".join([baseurl,"service/local/privileges"])
r = requests.get(url,auth=auth,headers=headers).json()
for priv in r["data"]:
    dict[priv["name"]]=priv["id"]

# print the privilege ID
print dict[<privilege you want>]
```